# How can I use neo4j / Cypher to identify a path that connects from one central node/label to 3+ other node/labels?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to use neo4j / Cypher to query a particular pattern in my neo4j database, and I can't figure out how to do it.

[image: Graph pattern]

I'm trying to output on one line, the Company name property, the Organization name property, the collection of category node name properties (via collect(tag.name)) and the sum of the investment amount properties.

I can easily trace to/from the company node and two other distinct types of nodes, but I can't figure out how to also trace the path of the third node.

For two nodes, I use:

```
MATCH (t)<-[]-(c:Company)-[]->(org:Organization)
RETURN org.name, c.name, collect (t.name)
```

I've tried using MERGE and UNION but haven't gotten them to work.  How can I extend this to include the other leg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out thanks to guidance from Neo4j GraphGists.

What worked was:

```
MATCH (t)<-[]-(c:Company)-[]->(org:Organization)
WHERE c.name = "MyCompany"
MATCH (c)<-[]-(f:Funding)
RETURN c.name, org.name, collect(t.name), sum(DISTINCT f.amount)
```

(and specifically on line 3 it needs to be (c) instead of (c:Company)